# Not use console.log but alert is similar to Java println

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript

how to use alerts in ts and also println similar to java? I say in the render of the component or module itself display an alert or I write content in the html component or module. I was too succinct?

Answer (score 1):

In angular you can either write on console and you can see the logs on the developer tools of your browser or you add to the HTML what you want to write on the file, usually this is done in Angular and other javascript frameworks via Bindings like so :

Html File

```
<button (click)="logText()">Log text on Click</button>

<div>{{myText}}</div>
```

Typescript file of the html component

```
export class YourComponent{
  myText:string;
  constructor() { }
  logText(){
    this.myText = 'ANYTHING I WANNA TYPE HERE'
  }
}
```

Comment: need in html <script src = "script.js">? because I gave a tsc heelo.ts

Comment: @GuilhermeLuizStolfo you mentioned angular and typescript, if you create a default angular app with the command 'ng new' it by default will have a app component.I just wrote generic code for an angular component

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log()

And open your browsers developer console

Comment: I didn't want to use an alert on typescript or a javascript writer but to write it on my own html